PyInstaller 1.26.4 -- Numpy Import Error on .exe
When attempting to convert my .py file to a .exe, the conversion goes as planned but when running the .py file I get the following errors:
`Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File <Filename>, line 17, in <module>  
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module  
  File "pandas\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>  
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:  
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from  
      its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python  
interpreter from there.  
[27328] Failed to execute script <Filename> due to unhandled exception!`

The script itself uses Pandas, so I believe I need numpy to be available.
How would I go about correcting this issue with the numpy dependency permanently?

I've tried multiple versions of both packages and am currently on the newest ones.
I've tried --hidden-import numpy without success or difference.
I've tried looking up similar solutions, but when researching this across StackOverflow, the most relevant answers I find refer to upgrading or downgrading packages due to PyInstaller and Numpy not playing nicely together, however the posts are old and outdated by several years and don't help in my situation.
Numpy - 1.26.4
PyInstaller - 6.7.0

Downgrading the numpy and pandas works for me.
numpy==1.21.5
pandas==1.4.2


I have the same issue with python 3.12.6 using pyinstaller 5.13.2. I using an older version of pyinstaller because of the way the pkging structure changed after 5.13.2
The issue was:
The numpy.libs dll are missing in the executable pkg created by pyinstaller.
The dlls are under:
\Lib\site-packages\numpy.libs
The Fix:
You can either manually copy the numpy.libs folder into the pkg after pyinstaller or modify your spec file to include those files
n_f=[]
for files in glob(sys.prefix + r'\Lib\site-packages\numpy.libs\*.*'):
    f2 = files,"numpy.libs"
    n_f.append(f2)
all_files.extend(n_f)

and then set datas = all_files in the Analysis
a = Analysis(['examples.py'],pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],binaries=None,datas=all_files,hiddenimports=[],hookspath=None,runtime_hooks=None,excludes=None)
